# Lambda function not being triggered by S3 bucket upload new file

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, upload

I am trying to trigger a basic lambda function when a new file gets uploaded to the S3 bucket.

I tried using the nodejs API call to create new files and also from the S3 bucket wizard upload button.

I check the CloudWatch logs and the function is never called even though I have several new files on my S3 bucket, here is my lambda configuration:

[image]

Object notification settings:

[image]

Any thoughts about the reason is not being called, thanks?

Comment: can share bucket notification settings?

Comment: Hey @AtharKhan just editted the question with the information you asked for, I think this is the information you want right?

Comment: Did you create the event through the lambda console? If so then the policy for it should be automatically added, but if not, check the lambda policy to see if it has access to that S3 bucket

Comment: Hey @Deiv, I didn't create the event, it was added automatically I believe when I created the trigger

Comment: Then the policy should be there...could you attach the lambda policy so we can confirm? Make sure to exclude your account id/bucket name or any other sensitive data

Comment: its working now! after using a new role based on a template which have access to the S3 bucket! thanks!